# Can I call my apex method from inside my JS?

Tags: apex, javascript

If I have a page like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="controller" extensions="other_controller">

    <style>
    </style>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //page contents rendered with jQuery - not very much content
        )

    </script>

 </apex>
```

And I have a method which is called from my controller like so: `{!isAvailable}`

I want to stop the JavaScript from building the page if my method returns false.

Is there a way to call my method with JavaScript and stop the code from proceeding?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your variable wherever you'd like to prevent loading. There's two general methods you could use, depending on if you want the JavaScript to be rendered into the browser at all.

Examples:

```
<!-- entire script tag isn't rendered -->
<apex:outputText rendered="{!isAvailable}">
<script> ... </script>
</apex:outputText>

<script> jQuery(document).ready(function) {
    if(!{!isAvailable}) return; // abort early if not available
</script>
```

Comment: Cheers sfdcfox, much appreciated!